# Click button in a table via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, button, click

I'm trying to click on a button via Powershell that appears to be in a table. I have tried various versions of the click method below without success. Any ideas? TIA

Code:

```
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.type -eq "button"}
$Link.click()
```

Webpage:

```
<html>
 <head>_</head>
 <body>
  <div class="moto-global">
   <div class="moto-icon">
    <table class="table-icon" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="td-icon" width="20%" valign="middle">=</td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <img src="motolog.jpg" width="112px" height="82px">
          </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </td>
      <td width="55%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">
        <input class="moto-home-button" type="button" name value="Advanced"
        onclick="gotoAdvanced()">
        "
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="logout.asp" class="moto-logout-button">_</a>
         <span style="font-size: 18px;">Logout</span>
        </a>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 <div id="moto-content">=</div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? do you want to automating browser click?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to automate the button click. Thanks.